# Are potential complex zeros not on the critical line of Dedekind zeta function in quadruples?

Tags: zeta-functions

This question arose from sums over zeros of Dedekind zeta function.

It is known that complex zeros of Dedekind zeta function are in pairs $\rho, 1 - \rho$.

> Is it true that potential complex zeros not on the critical line of Dedekind zeta function must be in quadruples
>   $\rho, 1 - \rho, \overline{\rho}, \overline{1 - \rho}$ ?

I am interested in the general case, not for specific number fields
(or for number fields for which the answer is "no").

Comment: Siegel zeros are real by definition...

Comment: @David thank you, edited the question for complex zeros not on the critical line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional equation tells you that if $\rho$ is a zero, so is $1-\rho$.  On the other hand, since the Dirichlet series coefficients are real, we have that for $\text{Re}(s)>1$, $\zeta(\bar{s})=\overline{\zeta(s)}$.  By analytic continuation this holds for all $s\ne 1$.  So if $\rho$ is a complex zero off the critical line, so is $\bar{\rho}$.  This works for any Dirichlet series with functional equation and real coefficients, i.e. real quadratic character, elliptic curve,...